# UITableView reloadData does nothing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a "legacy" application with a table of individuals in a UITableView.  This app is several years old and I'm testing the iOS 7 upgrades.  Manual reference counting, non-storyboard, testing on a "real" iPad at iOS 6.x.

In the midst of a long operation all but two of about 300 rows in the table disappeared.  (The app is still running, doing an extended download operation.)

I can do several different things on the pad which cause it to execute `reloadData` on the table.  A stop at the `reloadData` shows the table pointer to be valid and the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table to match `self` (the owning view controller containing the delegate methods).  A `po` of the table shows a perfectly normal UITableView `description` dump.  And the missing rows are not simply scrolled off the display -- scrolling up and down only the two lone rows remain.

*Occasionally* `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` will be invoked, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never is.  (`numberOfRowsInSection` returns 353.)

This was running fine for at least a half hour before it went wonkers, and the code surrounding this table has not been touched in a year or so.

So I'm wondering what in the world could be causing this symptom.  Why would the system stop invoking the delegate methods?

**Update:**  I did find one case in the code where `reloadData` was being called from a background thread.  Changed that to perform on main thread.  The scenario then reran without incident, but of course that proves nothing.

Comment: Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not even called for the two rows you're seeing? What's the `dataSource` of the tableView set to?

Comment: Nope.  But good point about the dataSource -- I need to check that.

Comment: `dataSource` is set to `self` (the view controller) as well.

Comment: Are you calling reloadData in a background thread by chance?  Maybe it's getting a race condition from too many calls in the background and then nothing works from then on out?

Comment: @Putz1103 - It's possible that some of the calls are from a background thread.  The two I can most easily provoke are in the main thread, however.  And the `reloadData` spec has no cautions against background threads.  (Nothing in this code is inserting/deleting rows and there's no animation.)

Comment: (The long download is complete and it's still only the two rows.  The app seems perfectly functional otherwise.)

Comment: Can you scroll through the possible 353 cells, but only 2 are populated?  Or is it solely 2 cells?

Comment: @Putz1103 - There are only 2 cells displayed.  But, interestingly, if I scroll up 5 times I need to scroll down 5 times for the cells to reappear, so it seem as if maybe the cells are there, only blank.  So the question is, why is cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called?  (And why is numberOfRowsInSection only randomly called?)

Comment: Getting near quitting and I'll have to lock up.  Tried homing the app and bringing it back to foreground -- no effect.  (Rotating -- also no effect.)

Comment: How about completely closing the app and restarting it?  (hopefully you won't have to download again...)

Comment: @Putz1103 - I just did that -- the data came back just fine (as I expected it would).  I'm guessing something got wonked up inside the table view, but haven't a clue what it would be or what might have provoked it.  And not sure I'll ever reproduce this again.

Comment: Those are the worst problems.  I wish you luck, sorry there is no solution thus far.

Comment: @Putz1103 - Well, thanks for looking at it.

Comment: You should not be calling **anything** in UIKit on a background thread, unless stated otherwise. This may not be the problem here, but it's very important.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code(like didUnload/didreceiveMemoryWarning) you clear up either dataSource/delegate or tableView itself and because of dataSource is nil those methods are not called?

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov - No, I checked the tableView pointer and the delegate and dataSource settings within the tableView when the app was at a stop (did this several times), and everything was correct.